# Link to latest master build

Tags: artifactory

I have a product for which I store software builds in Artifactory.

I name the software artifacts like this, so it is possible to se what a downloaded file contains: `system-pcm33-base-v0.0.0.0_65_ga03970a.raucb`

Thus it is also possible to download directly via an URL, not using jfrog

```
https://artifactory.deif.com/ui/native/amc-sw/pcm33/master/system-pcm33-base-v0.0.0.0_65_ga03970a.raucb
```

Now I would like to make a quick way to download the latest master build. To do this I have in my build made a symlink

```
system-pcm33-base.raucb -> system-pcm33-base-v0.0.0.0_65_ga03970a.raucb
```

I can also push this symlink to artifactory, but it only works from the GUI and via jfrog. I do not get this symlink as I had hoped:

```
https://artifactory.deif.com/ui/native/amc-sw/pcm33/master/system-pcm33-base.raucb
```

Is there a way to do this?

It is of course possible to upload the file twice under two different names, and thus update `system-pcm33-base.raucb` on every build. But that is a bit more heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory doesn't handle symbolic links as in the Linux file system.

Based on the described use case, you can upload the file twice (as suggested) - first with the actual version, second as the latest. The important part is - when you upload for the 2nd time, as the latest, use [Checksum Deploy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactbyChecksum).

Artifactory has a [checksum based storage](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Checksum-Based+Storage), which means that every file is actually stored once, even if it is uploaded to different target paths. In order to tell Artifactory to create/update a path without actually sending the binary, you can send the checksum of the binary, and Artifactory will link the path to the binary with that checksum. This operation is quite cheap.

Another possible approach is to define and use a custom [Repository Layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts). This way, in order to download the latest version of the file, you can use the `[RELEASE]` placeholder. The actual latest version ill be automatically resolved by the extracted version value based on the layout.

See also:

- [How to create simple versioning custom layout in Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-simple-versioning-custom-layout-in-artifactory/)
- [How to find the latest artifact version based on layout?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-find-the-latest-artifact-version-based-on-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [yinon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3211710/yinon) explaining that the checksum is used, I found this simple solution

```
jf rt copy --flat amc-sw/pcm33/master/system-pcm33-base-v0.0.0.0_65_ga03970a.raucb amc-sw/pcm33/master/system-pcm33-base.raucb
```

This copies ALL the properties, but then a download query will return two files, so a property has to be changed

```
jf rt sp amc-sw/pcm33/master/system-pcm33-base.raucb artifact=last_bsp
```